# What is the difference between $K$ ,$K_{IC}$ and $K_t$?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, materials, stresses, finite-element-method

I have seen three representation of stress concentration factor values $K$,$K_{IC}$ and $K_t$ now all that I know is $_I$ in suffix represents opening mode of crack.The suffix $t$ stands for tip.However I do not understand how the three are factually different.I would require some fundamental advice on the three.

Comment: Where have you seen these? What was their ecplanation?

Comment: In the book,"Mechanical Behaviour of Materials" by Meyer and Chawla

Comment: And how was each explained? Or they just “appeared”?

Comment: They just appeared.